# correct use of the include file

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement

i am programming in php talking to mysql database. the code requires the use of different include files(connection to different databases) based on the user logged in. 
i was just wondering, what would be the correct way to do that. should include all the files in the beginning and then specify the database name inside my queries or keep including the files and not change the query.
for example, for user a the database access required is uae

```
if($user == 'a'){
include('/home/xxxxxxx/xxxxxx/connection.php'); // connection to database x
$qry = "SELECT * FROM sometable";
} elseif($user == 'b'){
include('/home/xxxxxxx/xxxxxx/connect.php'); // connection to database y
$qry = "SELECT * FROM sometable";
}
```

would the above be better or the following:-

```
include('/home/xxxxxxx/xxxxxx/connection.php'); // connection to database x
include('/home/xxxxxxx/xxxxxx/connect.php'); // connection to database y
if($user == 'a'){
$qry = "SELECT * FROM databaseX.sometable";
} elseif($user == 'b'){
$qry = "SELECT * FROM databaseY.sometable";
}
```

please advise. help is appreciated.

Comment: Unless x and y are two completely different dbs, say MSSQL and SQLite, there should be no need to maintain two different connection scripts. And even then there's better ways of selecting which db to use.

Comment: If you aren't using the connection outside of the `if-else`; then method 1 is better.

Comment: @MarcB thanks. can you advise me where can i find more info of better ways of selecting the databases. they are both MySql databases.

Comment: @mmdel http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this code the size of loading page is not increasing because we are including files based on condition.

```
if($user == 'a'){
include('/home/xxxxxxx/xxxxxx/connection.php'); // connection to database x
$qry = "SELECT * FROM sometable";
} elseif($user == 'b'){
include('/home/xxxxxxx/xxxxxx/connect.php'); // connection to database y
$qry = "SELECT * FROM sometable";
}
```

And in this code the size of loading page is increasing because we are loading all files at start

```
include('/home/xxxxxxx/xxxxxx/connection.php'); // connection to database x
include('/home/xxxxxxx/xxxxxx/connect.php'); // connection to database y
if($user == 'a'){
$qry = "SELECT * FROM databaseX.sometable";
} elseif($user == 'b'){
$qry = "SELECT * FROM databaseY.sometable";
}
```

If it is only concerned with database connection than I think you have to use `1st` approach.